# Python - unittests: compare some objects using their attributes instead if they are really the same object?

Tags: python, python-2.7, object, python-unittest, xlwt

I have method that sets data into class attribute.

So let say I run:

```
self._set_data(some_data)
print self._data
```

It prints me this information:

```
{'c2': {
    'column': 1, 
    'style': <xlwt.Style.XFStyle object at 0x7f4668a18dd0>, 
    'value': u'Argentina', 'row': 2}, 
'c1': {
    'column': 0, 
    'style': <xlwt.Style.XFStyle object at 0x7f4668a18dd0>, 
    'value': 'C is not Python', 'row': 0}}
```

So every key except `style` has simple data, so there is no problem checking what is expected when running unittests. But the problem I see with `style` key, it returns instantiated `xlwt` module's style object. Now even if I would create "same" style using same values to `__init__` it, unittest would still fail, because it would compare objects, so it would be different object. Does python standard unittest suite have something like that? Or I need extend unittests suite, so it would compare that specific object differently somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your tests you can create a mock style object which is initialized with the expected values, then compare it's `__dict__` attribute to the `__dict__` attribute of the tested style object.

```
if mock_style.__dict__ == tested_style.__dict__ :
    print('The styles are set correctly.')
```